# Vaadin Treetable - disable blue highlighting

Tags: java, vaadin

Is there any way to disable blue highlighting of selected items in a Vaadins TreeTable component (mostly it will be treenodes)?
Im using a flag to chose which items shouldnt be highlighted.
I've been working on it for a few days now but nothing seems to work as intended. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the tree table extends table, you can use a [cell style generator](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-table.html#components.table) and a bit of *table related CSS* in your [theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html). The samples above are probably not 100% what you're looking for, but they should get you started and with a bit of tweaking you'll get there:

**1) Java**

```
public class TreetableWithoutSelectionBackground extends VerticalLayout {
    public TreetableWithoutSelectionBackground() {
        // standard tree table setup
        TreeTable treeTable = new TreeTable();
        treeTable.setSelectable(true);
        treeTable.setItemCaptionMode(AbstractSelect.ItemCaptionMode.ID);
        treeTable.setItemCaptionPropertyId("caption");

        // cell style generator to decide whether the item should or should not have a background
        // since we'll be using a bean item container, the itemIds will be the beans themselves so we can use those directly
        treeTable.setCellStyleGenerator((source, itemId, propertyId) -> ((MyBean) itemId).shouldHaveBackground() ? null : "no-background");

        // standard container
        BeanItemContainer<MyBean> container = new BeanItemContainer<>(MyBean.class);
        treeTable.setContainerDataSource(container);

        // add some dummy data
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            boolean shouldHaveBackground = random.nextBoolean();
            container.addItem(new MyBean("Item - " + i + " [" + shouldHaveBackground + "]", shouldHaveBackground));
        }

        addComponent(treeTable);
    }

    // basic bean
    public static class MyBean {
        private String caption;
        private boolean shouldHaveBackground;

        public MyBean(String caption, boolean shouldHaveBackground) {
            this.caption = caption;
            this.shouldHaveBackground = shouldHaveBackground;
        }

        public String getCaption() {
            return caption;
        }

        public void setCaption(String caption) {
            this.caption = caption;
        }

        public boolean shouldHaveBackground() {
            return shouldHaveBackground;
        }
    }
}
```

**2) Theme/CSS**

```
@mixin mytheme {
  @include valo;
  // Insert your own theme rules here

  .v-table [class*="-row-no-background"].v-selected {
    background: transparent none; // no colour & no image
    color: black;                 // make the text visible as default selection makes it white
  }
}
```

**3) Result**

[image: tree table item background]

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you said with little tweaking it worked as intended.

Comment: @Artur no problem, glad you've figured it out